# Send mail using command line

Tags: command-line, sendmail

Can anyone help me out, we need to send mail through command line from Window server. We cannot use Blat as per security issue and neither do we want to install Exchange resource kit. We have our own Mail exchange server we can make use of it.

May be if any batch which could be run to access our SMTP mail server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the security issue with Blat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved without using any SMTP clients. I used Windows Powershell script to send mail and it is working very well.

Please check the below link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/10/30/sending-automated-emails-with-send-mailmessage-convertto-html-and-the-powershellpack-s-taskscheduler-module.aspx

Happy coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to install any SMTP client whatsoever, and just want to use windows and perhaps batch files, you could use Telnet to connect to port 25 of your smtp server and send the commands manually.
[Here is an example of how to do this](http://www.activexperts.com/activemail/telnet/).
Anyway, I personally would prefer to install some command line SMTP client such as Blat or [Bmail](http://www.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm), instead of going into the hassle of directly interacting with SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

a very nice solution I found generically good if **no authentication** is involved and **no programs can/should be installed or can be assumed to exist** is the following, which should work on Ubuntu and other Linux platforms alike (you can put everything in one line using the `;` command delimiter and removing the `\` chars in the `echo` quoted string):

```
set sender="<sender@example.com>"
set recipient="<recipient@example.com>"
set subj="testsubj"
set body="testbody"
set srv="mysmtpsrv.com"
set port="25"
set crlf="\x0D\x0A"

echo "EHLO man${crlf}\
MAIL FROM: ${sender}${crlf}\
RCPT TO: ${recipient}${crlf}\
data${crlf}\
Subject: ${subj}${crlf}${crlf}\
${body}\
${crlf}.${crlf}"\
|\
nc -Ci 1 ${srv} ${port}
```

(Using like this make sure you are saving the file in Unix style (only a `\x0A` character will be added after the `echo "...\` backslashes).
Otherwise just remove the backslashes and the newline which puts everything on a line and makes it work, but less visually structured.)

Answer (score 0):

HowToGeek demonstrates a Windows PowerShell script that works very well at [How To Send Email From the Command Line in Windows Without Extra Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/120011/stupid-geek-tricks-how-to-send-email-from-the-command-line-in-windows-without-extra-software/)

Here is the method:
First you're defining the variables:

> $EmailFrom = “yourMail@gmail.com”
>   $EmailTo = “theRecipient'sAddress@someServer.com”
>   $Subject = “your subject”
>   $Body = “some text”
>   $SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
>   $SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)
>   $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
>   $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential(“yourGmailUsername”, “password”);

Then, you're using this command to send the mail:

> $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)

You'll need a valid Gmail account in order to authenticate as a Gmail user.

Answer (score 0):

**To send mail from command line in windows:-**
Save this in a text file and name that file something like **sendmail.ps1**

```
$EmailFrom = "from@gmail.com"

$EmailTo = "to@domain.com"

$Subject = "The subject of your email"

$Body = "What do you want your email to say"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com"

$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587)

$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true

$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("gmail_username", "password");

$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

*-Don't forget to put the valid email address and password.*

Now open CMD and write this command

> Powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:\sendmail.ps1

*Voila! mail sent!!*

Answer (score -1):

This is an example to send mail from your Gmail address, for other servers you need to change the -smtp and -port

$securepass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $yourpassword -A -F

$credential=new-object PSCredential $yourusername,$securepass

send-mailmessage -from "$yourusername@gmail.com" -to $recipient -subject "subject" -body "message" -smtpserver smtp.gmail.com -port 587 -usessl -credential $credential -encoding utf8

Here is the script that can send mail from your Gmail:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PC-Utilities-Downloader-355e5bfe